# How To Make A Board Game Piece With Vector Displacement

Tags: node-editor, displacement, procedural, mathematics, vector

My final outcome will be a flat plane with a displaced board game piece that I can move around. I started by making a cylinder come out of the plane.

[image]

Then I wanted to use RGB curves to shape a board game piece.
I tried for a while to turn this all into a vector I could use, but I just don't know how.

[image]

I'm using this less than and clamped add to make the plane under the cylinder full white so it doesn't change with the base of the game piece

P.S. I've tried putting my final b&w texture into the x and y sockets on a Combine XYZ node, and I've tried doing that but multiplying the combine to the vector I'm working from, every solution I've conceived always makes a cone shape, despite the RGB curve shape. I had some weird problems like this on another project where the outcome is pretty much not related at all to the nodes

Comment: Hello, it's hard to see, did you actually use a vector displacement node ?

Comment: I didn’t, I was watching a lot of tutorials where they didn’t and I didn’t really think to. If i did, how should I integrate my texture? Also I should I put the vector displacement mode before or after subtracting the original texture coordinates?

Comment: On DefaultCube's YT channel there are two interesting tutorials that might help you with this, there's this one called [The Romans Are Jealous](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS5Y0xBUvtA) where he uses RGB curves as well for shaping and which comes close to what you do. The other is [The ONLY Vector Displacement Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYfHcB6tVrU). I think in both he doesn't use a _Displacement Node_, it's just manipulating the normals and feeding them into the displacement socket of the output node.

Comment: @Gorgious You don't need a _Displacement Node_ if you're manipulating normals directly instead of converting a height map or something similar to normals.

Comment: I cannot edit my first comment anymore... so I think my linked tutorials are unnecessary because it seems like you already followed them to create this, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the second screenshot it seems like the RGB curves only contribute to the *Viewer Node*, they are not in any way connected to the *Displacement Output Socket*.

[image: missing connection]